# Fixed Menu Automatic Resizing and Minimum Window Size

Tags: html, css, flash, window, size

I asked a question yesterday:
[Fixed Menu at the Top of Webpage that Changes Size as Window Resizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850824/fixed-menu-at-the-top-of-webpage-that-changes-size-as-window-resizes/30863921#30863921)

I've updated a few things, and now it's looking much closer to what I want it to be. B,ut I just have a few follow up questions that I hope someone can help me with.

Please see what I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/ovr8spfu/6/

I would like to set a minimum width to my `#container`. I tried `min-width:950px` in `#container`, but to no avail. I want to do this because if you minimize the window now, the menu items disappear, first "Home" disappears, and then on and on. I'd like a minimum width so that the green filler part all goes away, afer that, a scroll bar should appear at the bottom of the window to fit the 950px menu.

My flash file is 1300x500. I want it to always fit the width of my window, with no padding, no background visible. So for example if the window is 1500 in width, the flash file should scale and stretch to 1500x577. If the window becomes its minimum (950 from question #1), the flash file should scale down to 950x365. The flash file should also always be touching the menu, and `#section` should be directly beneath it.

Lastly, if my menu item has a lot of text, how do I set a max width and text wrap to it? I'd like to wrap the text on 2 lines with a narrower menu item.

Thank you very much!